# curl "No route to host" or "Connection timed out" but python httplib works

Tags: web-server, curl, qemu

I have qemu guest instance which has an interface with `192.168.0.4` static ip address. Also there is virtual interface `tap0` without ip address and `br0` which has `192.168.0.3` ip address on the host.

There are the commands which I used to set up bridge:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip addr flush dev br0
ip addr add 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 dev br0
ip tuntap add mode tap user $(whoami)
ip link set tap0 master br0
ip link set dev br0 up
ip link set dev tap0 up
```

A web-server is running inside qemu. When I try to perform simple get request with curl like this `curl 192.168.0.4:8080` from the host, I get `No route to host` error message. But if I perform the same request by python `httplib.HTTPConnection("192.168.0.4:8080")`,
I receive response `200 OK`.

Could you please give me an advice to solve this issue with curl.

Comment: You're using IP addresses which belong to the US Department of Defense. If you are _not_ in the DoD you should probably fix that.

Comment: @michael-hampton fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `curl` is using proxy settings retrieved from environment variables and that proxy does not know a route to `192.168.0.0/24` network.

Please, try the following:

```
$ curl --verbose --noproxy '*' 192.168.0.4:8080
```

Comment: Thank you! Your command is working :)